# how to set the memory parameter in a Gurobi model using c++ language

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-management, gurobi

I'm trying to set a memory limit to my Gurobi Model.

```
GRBEnv env = GRBEnv(true);
env.set("LogFile", "Model_DEBUG.log");
env.start();
GRBModel model = GRBModel(env);
model.getEnv().set(GRB_DoubleParam_MemLimit, 8);
```

But, this doesn't work. How could I set this parameter?

I'm trying to set 8Gb of ram to my gurobi model, considering the c++ language

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "this doesn't work"?

Comment: Yes, of course! I had used the Gurobi 9.1.1 and in some mathematical problems, I had the memory limit reached. So, reading the documentation I found the MemLimit parameter. I tried to set the memory limit through GRB_DoubleParam_MemLimit, but in my version, this parameter doesn't exist how GRB_DoubleParam, only in the Gurobi 10.0. Later, I knew the memory limit must be defined in the environment in version 9.5. I've installed version 10.0 and I'm trying to validate my academic key to test MemLimit. I'll post feedback here on how to set the memory limit to document both forms (both 9.5 and 10).